# What are the functions of the include, share, lib directory and subdirectories and files in the postgres installation directory?

Tags: postgresql

[image]

What are the functions of the include, share, lib directory and subdirectories and files in the postgres installation directory?

Comment: They make up the Postgres server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are part of the PostgreSQL software.

- `include` contains the C header files needed to

  - compile client applications that use the C client library `libpq` and
  - compile server extensions to PostgreSQL.
- `lib` contains

  - static and dynamic libraries for linking client applications,
  - dynamic libraries that are part of the PostgreSQL server and
  - dynamic libraries that contain PostgreSQL extensions.
- `share` contains other files like

  - message files to translate PostgreSQL messages into various languages,
  - time zone data,
  - configuration files for full text search,
  - templates for configuration files and
  - extension configuration files and scripts.